# How to assign the same name for a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a grid view which has dynamic columns and i want to assign a hidden field to the columns which contains the same name.
This loop creates the columns of the grid view

```
for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
 $('<td>' + result1[i] + '</td>').appendTo($('#trr'));
}
```

and i want to add this same date 2019-12-02 to every column it creates as a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" value="2019-12-02" class="th-hidden-date" />
```

I have no idea of doing this..
If anyone got any idea ,it would be so helpful for my project.
Much appreciated.. 
can i access the class when it loops and create the hidden field.

Comment: which is the value of `result` array ? And the value of the input is always that string ? or it depends on some variable ?

Comment: what are the values comes in result1[i] array? Do you want append the hidden fields in td?

Comment: @MihaiT result[i]  contains all the dates that the  user inputs

Comment: @Ranjith.V  result[i] contains all the dates that the user inputs

Comment: So the values ( dates ) from the `result` you want to add them as values to the inputs ?

Comment: @MihaiT So according to my loop it creates the columns dynamically but i want to get those dates again and create a hidden field with the same dates.

Comment: and append that field inside the column ? Check my answer below and comment on it if you need further changes

Comment: @MihaiT it worked thanks alot.. How can i get the values of the hidden fields ? Can we get them like                                                                                            var ask_id = $('#trr').val();
alert(ask_id);

Comment: No, you must select the inputs. `$('#trr input').each(function() { alert ($(this).val()) })` something like that. I edited the answer with this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `result[i]` as the value to your input. And append that input inside the `td`.
Check below

EDIT : if you want to get the values of the inputs later on see the edited snippet

```js
var result = ['2019-12-02', '2020-02-25', '1970-01-01']
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  var input = `<input type="hidden" value=${result[i]} class="th-hidden-date" />`
  $('<td>' + result[i] + input + '</td>').appendTo($('#trr'));
  
}
// to get the values of the inputs later on
$('#trr input').each(function() { 
  console.log ($(this).val()) 
});
```

```css
#trr td {
  border:1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="trr"></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution

```
for (var i = 0; i <= days; i++) {
 $('<td>' + result1[i] + '<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="2019-12-02" class="th-hidden-date" />' +'</td>').appendTo($('#trr'));
}
```

Add your hidden input in your `td` and get it's value whenever you want.

Comment: i tried this but the hidden values are not been hidden in the grid